# Somar Campos Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando realizar a soma de alguns campos em um `input final.

Tenho um `input` de id `#TotalFR` e gostaria que, conforme os campos `#CFR1`, `#CRF2`, `#CRF3`, `#CRF4` e `#CRF5` forem preenchidos, a soma deste seja apresentada em `#TotalFR`. Estou usando o script mas recebo o valor NAN como resposta.

```
 $('.vut').blur(function(){
   var id=$(this).attr("id").substr(3,1);
   $.ajax({
     url : 'custofr.php', 
     type : 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */ 
     data: 'FR1=' + $('#FR'+id).val() + '&VUT1=' + $('#VUT'+id).val(), 
     dataType: 'json', 
     success: function(data){
       if(data.sucesso == 1){
         $('#CFR'+id).val(data.CFR1);
         var Valor1=parseFloat($('#CFR'+id).val());
         var Valor2=parseFloat($('#TotalFR').val());
         var TotFR = Valor1 + Valor2;
         $('#TotalFR').val(TotFR);
       }
     }
   }); 
   return false; 
 })
```

Comment: Se tentar aplicar parseFloat em "" ou em um decimal com virgula, você recebe NaN como retorno. NaN + Num = NaN. Acho que #TotalFR está causando esse problema por estar vazio. Tenta trocar o parse float pelo operador de +. Não vou comentar isso como resposta por ser especulação, mas se resolver avisa aqui :)

Comment: Willian, muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento, isso ajudou a resolver o problema. Fiz a inserção de uma condicional que testa o campo para ver se está vazio, caso sim, atribui o valor 0, assim a conta procede de maneira correta. Inseri apenas a condição: if (isNaN(Valor2)){
 Valor2 = 0;
 }

Comment: Thiago, a sugestão do @WilliamBarbosa era mais simples, era só usar `+$('#CFR'+id).val()` (idem pro segundo valor). `+""` vira `0`. Aí nem precisa checar vazios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tentar aplicar `parseFloat` em uma string vazia (`""`) ou em um decimal com virgula, você recebe `NaN` como retorno e `NaN + Num = NaN.`

`#TotalFR` está causando esse problema por estar vazio. Sua melhor alternativa é usar o operador `+`, que vai tentar converter seu valor para um número e retornar `0` quando encontrar `""`

```
+$('#CFR'+id).val()
```

Lembrando apenas que se você estiver usando vírgulas para os números decimais, o NaN continuará aparecendo e você precisará fazer uma comparação, checando se o valor é NaN antes de usa-lo. Caso não esteja usando ponto, pode ignorar essa parte.